# First line at PDF doc is tabbed (LaTeX, R Sweave)

Tags: r, latex, sweave, underline

my problem is now the first line of the PDF-Document:

```
\underline{PDF-Document:}[l]\\%
~\\
```

In this way it begins with a TAB. With [l] I wanted that the first line remains left, but [l] isnt accepted and is printed, so it is shown at the PDF doc.

Thanks and best regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using

```
\begin{flushleft}\underline{PDF-Document:}\end{flushleft}
```

soled the problem.

Are there better options than using "flushleft", some solution with any box-Class? Now I am using for all texts "flushleft".